# Any idea on how to make the input for an "exit game" function like this work?

Tags: c++, input, cin

```
void Computer::playerMove(void)
{
    Features exitGame;
    int x, y;

    cout << "\nPlayer turn! You are X\n";
    cout << "________________________\n";
    cout << "Enter X Coordinate : " << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter Y Coodinate:" << endl;
    cin >> y;

    x--; y--;
 
    if (grid[x][y] != ' ') {
        cout << "\nSpace is filled/invalid !!\nPlease try AGAIN:\n";
        playerMove();
    }
    else grid[x][y] = 'X';
}
```

I want to make it seem like:
if user inputs 0, it EXIT's.

I'm kinda stumped and I can't think of anything else to do, I just want suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "it EXIT's." ? `if (x == 0) std::terminate();` ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to know where to find the problem.

Comment: Apart from that - how about something like `while (playerInput != '0') { playerMove(); } return 0; // or exit(0) etc.`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes, exactly that I think..

Comment: calling `std::terminate()` is only the last resort when you don't know what else to do. Given the lack of information and context, I didn't know what else to suggest. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @taiBsu Okay I'll try that

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 basically if you input the number 0 and only the number 0, the program will terminate but idk how to implement that here. If you press I think 1-3 the program will do something, that's why I chose 0 to be the one to exit this program (but I haven't put an exit function that can exit it when 0 is pressed yet)

Comment: If you're already getting stuck at this kind of questions, you might be interested in learning about the [basics of game programming](https://thatgamesguy.co.uk/cpp-game-dev-1/). There's tons of tutorials out there to help you get your thoughts straight on things like main loops etc.

Comment: you should add that information to your question. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67432667/edit) it. If `std::terminate()` is what you want then it might be just fine to call it

Comment: @taiBsu alright thank you so much!

Comment: @NavNaz don't forget to upvote comments you like. :D